# Enable/Disable Kernel Configuration options in Yocto

Tags: security, linux-kernel, yocto, drivers, kbuild

I have a configuration option called `CONFIG_X86_SMAP` that I would like to disable in my kernel image. The problem is that I can't identify where this option is being set. I can confirm that it isn't set in my `defconfig` file and also it's not set by any configuration fragment "`.cfg`".

Even when I try to disable it using a `.cfg` as follows:

```
# CONFIG_FOO is not set
```

I still find it enabled in my final generated .config file. I cant get to understand how this option is being enabled.

Note: There is no dependency on this configuration option from any other driver/feature.

Comment: Is your layer priority sufficiently high?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Yes, this layer has the highest priority!

Comment: Which kernel recipe do you use? Which OpenEmbedded version do you have?

Comment: Have you tried writing your layer in the first lines of the bblayer.conf file? Setting the priority doesn't seem to work for me. Are you cleaning the kernel with `bitbake -c cleansstate virtual/kernel` before you bitbake again?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your defconfig by following these steps.

1. Identify in which tasks .config is generated.(In most cases there would be do_configure or do_defconfig task that will create your .config)
2. Add following lines in your recipe(linux-kernel.bb file).This will append configurations to your defconfig file.

`do_confiure_prepend() { 
   cat >> <path_to_your_defconfig> << END 
   CONFIG_X=y
   CONFIG_Y is not set
   END
 }`